# State of the Art/Research 2020 of Time Series Forecasting/Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, xgboost, forecasting

Im looking for the state of the art/research of time series data for forcasting/prediction.
As far as im aware it is Extrem Gradient Boosting (XGBoost) or LSTM (neuronal networks) or are there other algorithms/models/methods which achieve good results.

I have a very small dataset less than 1000 data points. my guess/results are that LSTM has way to less data and XGBoost is the better alternative but im fairly new to forcasting so maybe im missing a method/model.

Comment: Start with a small model and push for « state of the art » if you really need to improve / if you don’t need to understand what your model does. Honestly, with 1000 sample, I don’t believe a deep method will be usefull.